# Have right-click browser menu of open link in new tab with knockout click binding

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a div on which I am doing knockout click binding. Inside of the function that is called through binding, I am doing `window.open` to navigate to a different page.

However, I want users to have an experience similar to clicking on a traditional link where you get the default browser menu of open link in new tab, similar to this

[image: Sample]

So is there any way to get this with a div?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is still using a link.You simply have to format it to look like a div, which in fact, doesn't have an special look, until you format it.

```css
.someClass {
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="someClass">
    I'm a link that looks like a div. Right click on me!
</a>
<br/>
<div class="someClass">
    I'm a div
</div>
```

Comment: Jota, sorry if I'm replying to an old question, but I'm currently having the same problem. What if your href is "#" and the correct URL is being set by knockout's onclick event handler? Will right menu item 'Open in new tab' do the right thing?